# Trouble adding a row to a 2D ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, arraylist

I'm trying to read a line from a .txt file into a 1D Array, add two more elements to that Array based data from the previous ones, and store the new and larger Array in a 2D ArrayList called "dataArrayList", then repeat with the subsequent lines in the .txt file.

```
public static ArrayList<String[]> dataArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

public static void readFile() throws Exception {
    fileRead = new FileReader(txtFileLocation);
    dataReader = new BufferedReader(fileRead);

    String line = "";

    String[] temp;
    String[] temp2 = new String[15];

    //reading the text file
    for (int i = 0; line != null; i++) {
        line = dataReader.readLine();
        if (line != null) {

            //line has 13 Strings to split
            temp = line.split(",");

            //making a larger duplicate with 15 indices instead of 13 as to add 2 more Strings
            System.arraycopy(temp, 0, temp2, 0, temp.length);

            /*
            my code to assign values to the two new 
            elements based data from the previous ones
            */

            //adding temp2 to my ArrayList
            dataArrayList.add(temp2);
        }
    }
}
```

It seems like it should work, but when I access dataArrayList afterwards, either by printing it out or putting it into a JTable, all the records are copies of the last line of the .txt file.

For example, if the .txt file looked like this (apologies for unintended syntax highlighting):

```
Hello,my,name,is,Hunter,how,are,you,doing,on,a,lovely,day,like,this
Have,you,heard,about,the,weather,we're,supposed,to,get,a,lot,of,rain,later
Hopefully,it's,sunny,for,the,entire,day,tomorrow,I,have,a,soccer,game,that,day
```

The first time it adds a record, dataArrayList looks as you expect it to, like this:

```
Hello,my,name,is,Hunter,how,are,you,doing,on,a,lovely,day,like,this
```

However, after it runs over a second time and "adds" the second line, it looks like this:

```
Have,you,heard,about,the,weather,we're,supposed,to,get,a,lot,of,rain,later
Have,you,heard,about,the,weather,we're,supposed,to,get,a,lot,of,rain,later
```

And finally, after it adds the third record, it looks like this:

```
Hopefully,it's,sunny,for,the,entire,day,tomorrow,I,have,a,soccer,game,that,day
Hopefully,it's,sunny,for,the,entire,day,tomorrow,I,have,a,soccer,game,that,day
Hopefully,it's,sunny,for,the,entire,day,tomorrow,I,have,a,soccer,game,that,day
```

I don't understand what's happening... It seems like it's overwriting the previous records with the current one.

Comment: Try adding `temp2 = new String[15];` as the last line of your loop

Comment: Happy to help. Please select my answer as correct. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `temp2 = new String[15];` as the last line of your loop

```
for (int i = 0; line != null; i++) {
        line = dataReader.readLine();
        if (line != null) {

            //line has 13 Strings to split
            temp = line.split(",");

            //making a larger duplicate with 15 indices instead of 13 as to add 2 more Strings
            System.arraycopy(temp, 0, temp2, 0, temp.length);

            /*
            my code to assign values to the two new 
            elements based data from the previous ones
            */

            //adding temp2 to my ArrayList
            dataArrayList.add(temp2);
            temp2 = new String[15];
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would also recommend not to use System.arraycopy and stay with the utility classes instead: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html

Answer (score 0):

The following line of code modifies the content of the variable temp2

```
   System.arraycopy(temp, 0, temp2, 0, temp.length);
```

You add the same variable successively to the list

```
   dataArrayList.add(temp2);
```

That's why temp2 contains the last line of the text file and list is just a repetition of the same line.
I suggest

```
   for (int i = 0; line != null; i++) {
    line = dataReader.readLine();
    if (line != null) 
    {

        //line has 13 Strings to split
        String[] temp = line.split(",");
        //convert to list in order to add strings
        ArrayList<String> templist = (ArrayList<String>) Arrays.asList(temp);
        temp=null;
        //add strings to your array by using templist.add(the_string);
        temp = new String[templist.size()];
        temp = templist.toArray(temp);
        templist=null;
        dataArrayList.add(temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not downvoting your answer, but OP said that he needs to add 2 more elements to array based on some logic. Your code won't allow that.

Comment: It's better now. But still, too much of time would be consumed just in type conversion. Moreover, `Arrays.asList()` returns a fixed-size array. see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29